# Jmeter MongoDb Getting Unauthorised

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to insert data(load test) from jmeter to mongodb getting unauthorized error but its connecting to DB.
Connection Code:

```
String mongoUser = "user"
String userDB = "mysyt"
char[] password = "password".toCharArray();

MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, userDB, password);

    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
            builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("xxx.xx.xxx.xx",27017)))}
        .build();

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);

    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mysyt");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("user");

    vars.putObject("collection", collection);


Error:

Response code:500 Response message:Exception: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command insert requires authentication' on server xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1580126230, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command insert requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1580126230, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": "j7ylgmDSaPsZQRX/SwPTo4ZSTII=", "$type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "6785074748788310018"}}}}
```

If I configure like this

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://user:password@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017/?authSource=mysyt&ssl=true");

    //MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);

    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mysyt");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("user");

    vars.putObject("collection", collection);
```

Error:

```
Response message:Exception: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake}, caused by {java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}}]
```

Insertion code:

Collection name was configured in user defined variables(TestPlan)

```
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");

    Document document = new Document("userId", "user1").append("userName", "kohli");
    collection.insertOne(document);

    return "Document inserted";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an instance of [MongoCredential](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/MongoCredential.html) but not passing it to the [MongoClientSettings.Builder](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings.Builder.html), the correct code would be something like:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyToClusterSettings { builder ->
            builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("xxx.xx.xxx.xx", 27017)))
        }
        .credential(credential) // this line is essential
        .build();
```

Check out the following material:

- [MongoDB Driver Tutorials -> Connect to MongoDB -> Authentication](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/tutorials/authentication/)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter/)

Going forward it would be nice to include the exact version of your [Mongo Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) as API may change from release to release and instructions valid for the driver version 3.6 will not work for the driver version 4.0 and vice versa